# xPages and Oracle - doing a query, I want to know how many result I have

Tags: oracle, view, xpages, relational

I am using a View Panel and I am connecting to an Oracle table.  I can see the results in my column.

I would like to put at the top of the view :   results : XX documents retrieved

Is there a way to do this ?

Anybody has an example ?

Thanks a lot

Sebastien

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a jdbcRowSet data source, you can use the `getCount` method

```
<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xe:jdbcRowSet var="jdbcData2" connectionName="mysql"
          sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY lastname"></xe:jdbcRowSet>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2"
      value="#{javascript:jdbcData2.getCount();}"></xp:text>
</xp:panel>
```

Alternatively you could just use the `getRowCount` method of the view panel control:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" 
  value="#{javascript:return getComponent('viewPanel1').getRowCount();}"></xp:text>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian, we managed to get number of values with your example.